# Format similar to Json

Tags: json, format

I am running into a problem, I don't know what data format this is:

"s:70:"a:2:{s:3:"url";s:28:"https://www.websitetest.com/";s:4:"text";s:0:"";}";"

It looks like JSON but it is not, has anyone ever seen something like this?

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949866/is-this-json-and-how-to-replace-values-with-php-variables)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a serialized PHP array.
Try to execute the following code

```
<?php 
$array = array("url" => "https://www.websitetest.com/", "text" => "");
echo serialize($array);
?>
```

and you will receive the following output:

```
a:2:{s:3:"url";s:28:"https://www.websitetest.com/";s:4:"text";s:0:"";}
```

as you can see it is slightly different, because in practice what you have is a double serialize.
executing the folling code woyu have your string.

```
<?php
$string = 'a:2:{s:3:"url";s:28:"https://www.websitetest.com/";s:4:"text";s:0:"";}";';  
echo serialize($string);
?>
```