# Parsing a data format similar to JSON

Tags: java, json, api, rest

I have an issue with the data returned by one of the APIs I use.

It returns data in the below format

```
[
{Invoice_Date=23-05-2021, Invoice_Number=3502111740, Invoice_Total=34543, Purchase_Order_Number=52004321, Result=true, File Path=D:\Accounts\Invoice Processing
}
]
```

The data has a hierarchy like a JSON Array but it uses "=" instead of ":" and the key values don't have double-quotes.
Also, I found some other format in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979814/format-similar-to-json) but not the format I got.
Can someone please tell me what format this is and how I can parse it in Java.
I don't prefer to split by "},{" and "," since the values might contain these characters. I will use that as a last resort.

Comment: what API does this come from? Does it have a specification that describes the format?

Comment: It is an API from a proprietary tool. returns this in text format. I could not find any documentation on the output format. Other APIs from the same tool all return perfect JSON. I have raised a ticket with the tool provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to change the whole object that you receive in a JSON object and then use one of the existing Frameworks to parse it in a POJO.

I am supposing that you take the response above as a `String`.

The function below should do the work.

```java
public String weirdResponseToJsonString(String weirdResponse)
    {
        weirdResponse = weirdResponse.replace("{", "{\"");
        weirdResponse = weirdResponse.replace("=", "\":\"");
        weirdResponse = weirdResponse.replace(",", "\",\"");
        return weirdResponse.replace("}", "\"}");
    }
```

Note that all the values will be treated as `Strings`.